# show that if two trees have isomorphic line graphs , they are isomorphic.

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

i want to use Whitney isomorphism theorem : if the line graphs of two connected graphs are isomorphic , then the underlying graphs are isomorphic. except in the case of the triangle graph K3 and K1,3 , which have isomorphic line graphs but are not themselves isomorphic. whitney's theorem will work here since the trees are connected graphs , but where can I find a proof of Whitney's isomorphism theorem.
any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Harary's "Graph Theory" book has a chapter on line graphs (see Chapter 8), where Whitney's isomorphism theorem (Theorem 8.3) is proved.